# FlutteGray app bar problem when opening app

Tags: flutter, appbar, flutter-appbar

After clicking the application icon, the first screen I see while opening the application is not the splash screen, a gray appbar screen.

native splash screen should come first, then its own splash should come

[image]

Comment: Please reproduct some code. So the community can help you out

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.